# How to get new content on the page, without a page refresh

Tags: javascript, ajax, refresh

If you look at Foursquares webpage : https://foursquare.com/

They have the new feeds automatically coming in without refreshing the page.  I am building a backend where we can look at user speciefic feeds.  How can i do get the same effect that Foursquare is using?

Comment: AJAX. It's javascript, so you can read their source.

Comment: @Wooble anywhere i can start with a script?

Answer (score 1):

It's a mix of `setInterval` and their ajax call.

```
setInterval(1000, function() {
    // Make ajax call here to get more information and append new elements to the DOM.
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a pretty good introduction to AJAX:

http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/default.asp